# Create Parent and Child from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I need to implement one collapsible diagram using d3. But first, it is necessary to parse my json file in order to create correct hierachies.

This is my json file example which I need transform:

```js
{"likes":[{"_id":null,"category":"Music","link":"https://www.facebook.com/Brum","name":"Brum"},
{"_id":null,"category":"Music","link":"https://www.facebook.com/pan", "name":"Pan FM"},
{"_id":null,"category":"Music","link":"https://www.facebook.com/Example","name":"Example"},
{"_id":null,"category":"Books","link":"https://www.facebook.com/foo","name":"Foo"},
{"_id":null,"category":"Movies","link":"https://www.facebook.com/Titanic","name":"Titanic"}]}]}
```

And this the structure that I need extract from my json file:

```js
var Data = [{
  "name": "SocialProfiles",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [{
"name": "Likes",
"parent": "SocialProfiles",
"children": [{
    "name": "Music",
    "parent": "Likes",
    "children": [{
      "parent": "Music",
      "name": "Brum"
    }, {
      "parent": "Music",
      "name": "Pan FM"
    }, {
      "parent": "Music",
      "name": "Example"
    }]
  },

  {
    "name": "Books",
    "parent": "Likes",
    "children": [{
      "parent": "Books",
      "name": "Foo"
    }, {
      "parent": "Books",
      "name": "Foo"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Movies",
    "parent": "Likes",
    "children": [{
      "parent": "Movies",
      "name": "Titanic"
    }]
  }
]
  }]
}];
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you need to do. Are you trying to analyse the original data, and reorganise it to be in the structure of the second snippet? How would you decide what goes where? And where do the extra things like "SocialProfiles" come from?

Comment: properly indenting your data in your second box would make it possible to see what the structure should actually look like

Comment: @Whothehellisthat, I edited the question, I hope that is more comprehensible. In short, I need transform my source json file in the structure that was exemplified...

Comment: Okay. Thanks. The thing, is I still don't know where "SocialProfiles" comes from (it's not anywhere in the input JSON). Is that just hardcoded in, and the rest added?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat, thanks by comments. And yes, "SocialProfiles" is just a label hardcoded...